# Compare Date field with the Today's in the linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using the EF and in the Linq query where clause I am trying to compare today's date with a date column in the Azure SQL Server database table.

Column in the table:

[image]

Field in the model class:

```
public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
```

I tried multiple different ways check if the `OrderDate = today's date` in the Linq query but the query returns nothing even though there are orders with today's date on it

[image]

Below is my linq query

```
var orderData = from mo in _context.MOrders
                from cus in _context.Customers
                where mo.CustomerId == cus.CustomerId
                      && mo.OrderDate == DateTime.Today.Date
```

I tried `mo.OrderDate.Date == DateTime.Today.Date` too but no records are returned

Answer (score 0):

This is was my bad doing `mo.OrderDate.Date == DateTime.Today.Date` worked. But the issue was I was querying the data on 2021-10-29 12.01 am and looking for the query to return the orders of date 2021-10-28 thinking today is (2021-10-28)